# Joining columns to a sorted file

Tags: r, bedtools, wgs, cnv

I have had a segmentation file (copy number) like below

```
  Sample      Chromosome  Start      End          Segment_Mean
LP6008334-DNA_C02   1     10583      62271      -0.992452416
LP6008334-DNA_C02   1   17201069    17230953    -0.992452416
LP6008334-DNA_C02   1   17235034    17235196     0.592510084
LP6008334-DNA_C02   1   142781738   142967188   -0.992452416
```

I was using bedtools to count the number of markers in above genomic range (Start, End) when I got as below

```
1   10583   62271   6
1   10583   62271   6
1   10583   750153  75
1   14907   1062025 106
1   121009  245455  13
1   404187  5719467 532
1   732809  5726842 500
1   821926  1120377 31
1   952428  1179983 23
1   1181751 1469134 29
1   3458681 143542402   14010
1   5726844 5736229 2
1   5735836 16832446    1111
1   5736682 8081290 236
1   8353020 8476455 13
```

Basically the same files but the second one has extra last column for the number of marker but sorted one I then I can not matched this with the above sample names and Segment_Mean

How I can add the corresponding sample names and Segment_Mean to my second file?

I have tried this where I am getting this mess

```
DF <- left_join(df_res1,df, by = "Start")

> head(DF)
           Sample.x Chromosome.x     Start     End.x Num_Probes          Sample.y Chromosome.y     End.y
1 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1     10583     62271          9 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1     62271
2 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1     10583     62271          9 LP6008337-DNA_A07            1     62271
3 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1     10583     62271          9 LP6008460-DNA_F02            1    750153
4 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1  17201069  17230953         20 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1  17230953
5 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1  17235034  17235196          1 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1  17235196
6 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1 142781738 142967188         40 LP6008334-DNA_C02            1 142967188
>
```

Also with this I have some overlaps like

```
300 segment overlaps detected in file '/temp/hgig/fi1d18/man/examplefiles/res1.txt'.
```

First overlap detected between segments at lines 1 and 9.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a problem you have faced and solved a few times before.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited main post with what I HAVE TRIED

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange your text file into a sorted BED file:

```
$ tail -n+2 segmentation.txt | awk -vFS="\t" -vOFS="\t" '{ print $2, $3, $4, $1 }' | sort-bed - > segmentation.bed
```

Use BEDOPS `bedmap` with `--echo-map-id-uniq` and `--count` operators on merged regions:

```
$ bedmap --delim '\t' --echo --count --echo-map-id-uniq --fraction-map 1 <(bedops --merge segmentation.bed) segmentation.bed > answer.bed
```

The file `answer.bed` will contain merged intervals from `segmentation.bed` in the first three columns, the number of intervals from `segmentation.bed` which are contained entirely within the merged interval in the fourth column, and a unique listing of IDs of those contained intervals in the fifth column.

Comment: Sorry segmentation.txt is my output from DF <- left_join(df_res1,df, by = "Start")  ?

Comment: Sorry, you said you were using command-line tools, so I assumed that was the case here. Can you use `write.table` or similar to write data out of R to a text file?

Comment: I have already written DF dataframe drown by DF <- left_join(df_res1,df, by = "Start") as a txt file and uploaded that in where terminal can find that.

Comment: Sorry says [fi1d18@cyan01 examplefiles]$ tail -n+2 segmentation.txt | awk -vFS="\t" -vOFS="\t" '{ print $2, $3, $4, $1 }' | sort-bed - > segmentation.bed
Non-numeric start coordinate.  See line 312 in -.
(remember that chromosome names should not contain spaces.)
[fi1d18@cyan01 examplefiles]$    This is the link of my whole DF file  https://www.dropbox.com/s/54923xx5ds6p52d/DF.txt?dl=0

Comment: Maybe start with exporting data before the left join step, i.e., the data you posted at the top of your question? While I can make an informed guess, I'm not 100% sure what `left_join` does in this case, and I probably don't have time to dig into R and debug its syntactic idiosyncrasies to solve this there. I do think the command-line approach that I suggested will help you solve your problem, as described, however. Good luck and I hope this helps!